# Android: Check which app is open on the screen

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone I am trying to make an app that will check which screen is open at the client and accordingly check: if an open app X will do ... and so on.  I would be happy for help on how to check which app is open to the customer on the screen.  And enslavement throughout Android

Comment: By 'screen is open' do you mean checking with a Service which application is running in the foreground?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I want my app to check which app is open.  On screen.  (When my app is not open on the screen. But will check which other apps are open on the screen) It is better to work even in the background that the app is closed.